# How to Sparse checkout with Tortoise Git?

Tags: tortoisegit, sparse-checkout

The working way to sparse checkout **using git bash** is:

```
git clone \
--depth 1  \
--filter=blob:none  \
--sparse \
https://github.com/darc-coder/FindMyQRApp \
cd test-git-partial-clone
git sparse-checkout set js
```

How do we sparse checkout this same code using **Tortoise Git - Git clone** tool? I am getting **unknown options error** while running this command.

[image: Git clone - Tortoise Git Window]

Comment: It seems the feature is not implemented. Here is an issue from 2015 asking for this, still open: https://github.com/guberm/tortoisegit/issues/1599

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 2.15 sparse checkout is not supported, yet.

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1599 and https://tortoisegit.org/issue/3667